# Close Window After Submission of Form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form

```
<form name="thumbnail" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" id="x1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" id="y1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" id="x2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" id="y2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" id="w" />
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" id="h" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Image" id="save_thumb"/>
    <?php $_SESSION['image1'] = $thumb_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'];?>
</form>
```

I want to close this form after completing this function

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#save_thumb').click(function() {
        var x1 = $('#x1').val();
        var y1 = $('#y1').val();
        var x2 = $('#x2').val();
        var y2 = $('#y2').val();
        var w = $('#w').val();
        var h = $('#h').val();
        if(x1=="" || y1=="" || x2=="" || y2=="" || w=="" || h==""){
            alert("Please Select Area to Crop");
        }else{

        return true;
        }
    });


});
```

Problem is that if I put window.close(); before return true; 
window closes but form does not submit, and if I put it after return true; then the window will not close.

This is not working

```
$("thumbnail").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serializeArray());
    window.close();
});
```

This is also not working:

```
function closeSelf(){
       document.forms['thumbnail'].submit();
       window.close();
}

<input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Image" id="save_thumb" onclick="closeSelf();"/>
```

Comment: Form submission needs to go to another page so it needs to submit the page. The code after it will not run. So you would need the code on the next page after the submission to call close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ajax form submission might help you out. On click you submit the form and the on completion of ajax request you can close the window. Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('[name="thumbnail"]').submit(function() {
        <Perform your validation here>
         $.ajax({
              url: $('[name="thumbnail"]').attr('action'),
              method: 'post',
              data: $('[name="thumbnail"]').serialize(),
              success: function (data, status) {
                 window.close();
               }

         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[name="thumbnail"]').submit(function() {
 var x1 = $('#x1').val();
    var y1 = $('#y1').val();
    var x2 = $('#x2').val();
    var y2 = $('#y2').val();
    var w = $('#w').val();
    var h = $('#h').val();
    if(x1=="" || y1=="" || x2=="" || y2=="" || w=="" || h==""){
        alert("Please Select Area to Crop");
    }else{
       $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serializeArray());
       window.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: no this is not working independently or when substituted for the clicked funtion

Comment: Sorry, the JQuery selector was wrong try the updated answer.

Comment: its closing but form action is not happening

Comment: Yes it does submit the form if jquery code is removed.